# How to log errors in APIGee

Tags: apigee

Is there any error logging option in APIGee?

I am enabling a proxy endpoint in APIGee for a customer. If there is any error in the flow, how can I log it to a persistent store?

Specifically, I am using javascript policies and parsing some of the returned by back-end service, format to a different format. If there is any parsing error, where and how can I log it?

I am able to catch the error with try catch block.
Can I send an email in the catch block to a specific email address?

Thanks,
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error in your catch block and then set the appropriate variable to contain the detailed error message you might have ran into.You can use syslog/messagelogging policy to send all the request details along with any parsing exception that you might have. You need some kind of a logging server at your end to be sent the logs to or you could also use public log management services, such as [loggly](https://www.loggly.com/). Refer to this section for more details - http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/log-messages-using-messagelogging

Answer (score 0):

Vineet I think you are looking to solve the following problems here:

1. During the coding process you want to debug and understand what is going on? Something that lets you log.debug equivalent.
2. You want to also trigger exception flows or external processes when things go wrong in your proxy flow.

For #1 you can assign variables and trace using apigee's debug view. Any flow variable assignment in Apigee policies is printed in the debug view, if the policy is executed.  So that provides you with log.debug mechanism, whenever you trace.

For #2 you can take a variety of approaches based on rest of your systems and processes. The previous answer by @Mike Dunker is a good approach. I can suggest a few more alternates

- As an alternate you can also use Apigee's analytics views to monitor errors, albeit after the fact.
- You can set up external monitoring scripts on your backend or on the apigee endpoint based on some synthetic transaction that touches upon the entire logic of your flow. When the services return error you can measure metrics and/or raise alert from your monitoring system.
- If you have an on-premise installation of Apigee, you may want to consume apigee log files on the servers and raise appropriate actions on errors.
- You can raise a desired error message to a JMS queue when error happens. Refer to Apigee's JMS support [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/jms-integration)